# Transfer windows to other hard disk

Tags: windows-8

My laptop came with 500GB of storage, which is very little to me. I want to put in a 1TB Hard Drive. Now my problem is, I want to copy my Windows 8 installation (installed by the OEM) to the new one.

I believe that Windows locks itself to the hardware, and changing parts (ie, the hard drive) will make it appear as a pirated copy. It this is not the case, how can I transfer the installation to other physical disk? I have an SATA-to-USB device to use if needed.

Comment: You are not correct that Windows is locked to the HDD. The simplest way is to create an image of the existing HDD, restore the image to the new HDD, and extend the partition ( because the restoration process will only create a single 500GB partition ) and the rest will not be allocated.  How you do this is well documented on this website and others so I won't repeat the information.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your hard drive will not deactivate Windows.  I suggest using [Clonezilla live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php).

Answer (score 0):

A utility like Acronis could do this fairly easily. Typically you boot to either a thumbdrive or CD environment to do the copy while the file system is down. AFAIK, windows only keeps track of certain hardware for piracy checks. These include big items like processors, north/south bridges, and other typically non-replaced items. Hard drives, RAM, cd drives, graphics cards swapping shouldn't trigger this behavior.

http://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/pc-backup/

Acronis is a pay solution, but I use it regularly at work and it works great. There are also a ton of free alternatives as well, but I can't comment on those.